# Can't disable placeholderReplacement for flyway in gradle?

Tags: gradle, flyway

Simple issue.

I am trying to disable placeholderReplacement in flyway. I am using gradle.

My config has this in it:

```
flyway {
    placeholderReplacement = false
    outOfOrder = true
    locations=['filesystem:./db/migration']
    ...
}
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate
  No signature of method: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.setPlaceholderReplacement() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [false]
  Possible solutions: setPlaceholderReplacement(boolean), isPlaceholderReplacement()
```

I'm pretty new to gradle and groovy, but I could not figure out how to get past this issue. I've tried adding single and double quotes and changing casing on the property. Also tried explicitly casting "false" to a boolean.

Other than that, I am at a loss. I am setting other boolean properties just fine, such as `outOfOrder`, but it only blows up on `placeholderReplacement` which makes me think that it might be an issue on the flyway side. I am following the examples from the flyway website line for line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Flyway are you on? Ensure you are at least on 3.2.1

Comment: @AxelFontaine I believe I am on 3.2.1. This is my gradle dependency, is this sufficient? `dependencies {
        classpath "org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.2.1"
        classpath "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22"
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue (https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1001) that has been fixed for 4.0 (due out this month).

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'll plan on working around this by changing the placholder prefix/suffix for now.